# Windows Task Scheduler running on multiple Virtual Machine instances

Tags: virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks

I suppose my question may expose my lack of knowledge about how VM instances operate. My understanding, as has been explained to me so far, is that each instance is identical to each other. If I have a Windows Scheduled Task (for simplicity, lets say that the task increments a counter each time it is run) on the source machine that the image is created from, and have 5 of the same instance running, will each of the 5 VMs try to complete that task, thus yielding a counter that increments by 5?

Comment: If you have 5 identical eggs & make an omelette out of one…

Comment: To add to Tetsujin's comment, imagine you had cloned the hard drive of a Windows machine and put that copied hard drive into 5 different physical machines. Would you expect the counters to all act individually? Or would you think they would increment the same counter? Or to make it even simpler, if you photocopied a form and gave that to 5 people, would they all add their answers together? Or would they each have their own completed form?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the hard drive copy analogy. From what I've been told, I'll have 1 SAN device and 5 VMs. So not 5 "copies" of the hard drive, just 5 copies of something (the VM) telling the SAN to increment the counter.

Comment: @Randomhero see above

Comment: If you have 5 VMs looking at the same hard drive location, and the same OS files, you are going to have a very bad time.
If you copy a VM and deploy it, it should have it's own files, isolated from the others. What Tetsujin and I were trying to say was that all the VMs *should* run without any input from the other devices. I think you may need to give some more information in your question, maybe with a diagram of how you think things are set up. For example, a SAN could be used by many VMs, but would still be isolated from one another.